# Erlang remote code loading via erl_boot_server not working

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm testing erlang remote code loading via -loader inet option without the slave option.

Two elixir emulators (consoles) on the same box for now. The master running a custom project:

**Master**

```
shell> iex --sname master --cookie abc123 -S mix

master iex> :erl_boot_server.start([{127,0,0,1}])
{:ok, #PID<0.134.0>}
```

The other running bare:

**Worker**

```
shell> iex --sname worker --cookie abc123 --erl "-hosts 127.0.0.1 -id worker -loader inet"

worker iex>
```

How does exacly the automatic remote code loading suppose to work? When I try to load module on the worker I get:

```
worker iex> Code.ensure_loaded(MyModule)
{:error, :nofile}
```

On the master this does work:

```
master iex> Code.ensure_loaded(MyModule)
{:module, MyModule}
```

I know the worker node does find the master and connect to it's boot server because when the master is not present, I get the message:

```
{erl_prim_loader,'no server found'}
```

I have tried also to add all the code paths to the worker via Code.append_path but still when I try to load the module it does not find it.

Comment: I think it'll work if on the worker you instead call something like `Code.ensure_loaded(:myModule)`, i.e., using the atom form of the module name.

Comment: @SteveVinoski I have tried it now and also the full name :"Elixir.MyModule". Same results of no file found. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Strange. Aside from the `-S mix` option I've run the same commands as you and can load modules using the atom module names. I even ran `dtruss` on my Mac to verify the boot loader is reading and sending the files to the worker and that the worker wasn't loading them from disk itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this on your master:

```
:rpc.call(:'worker', :code, :add_paths, [:code.get_path])
```

Once that is done, you should be able to load your code automatically on the worker node.